# Express: Setting content-type based on path/file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mime-types

I know Express has the res.contentType() method, but how do I automatically set content type based on path/file (including static content)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js) will automatically set the content type, unless you explicitly set it yourself. Here's the snippet that does it. It uses [mime.lookup](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime) and mime.charsets.lookup

```
// mime type
type = mime.lookup(path);

//<SNIP>....

// header fields
if (!res.getHeader('content-type')) {
  var charset = mime.charsets.lookup(type);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', type + (charset ? '; charset=' + charset : ''));
}
```

If this isn't working for you, post your code as your custom code is likely interfering with the default behavior somehow.

Comment: `mime.lookup()` is now renamed to `mime.getType()`.

Answer (score 42):

Also, if you want to extend the mime-types that express(connect) knows about, you can do

```
express.static.mime.define({'text/plain': ['md']});
```

or

```
connect.static.mime.define({'text/plain': ['md']});
```

PS: the mime module is now located at https://github.com/broofa/node-mime

Comment: FYI: If you need to tinker with the charset, look in the "send" lib that express static requires (node_modules/send)

Answer (score 23):

The [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) shows that it can do this if you pass in the file name.

```
var filePath = 'path/to/image.png';
res.contentType(path.basename(filePath));
// Content-Type is now "image/png"
```

**[Edit]**

Here's an example which serves files from a relative directory called `static` and automatically sets the content type based on the file served:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');

var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/files/:file', function(req, res) {
  // Note: should use a stream here, instead of fs.readFile
  fs.readFile('./static/' + req.params.file, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      res.send("Oops! Couldn't find that file.");
    } else {
      // set the content type based on the file
      res.contentType(req.params.file);
      res.send(data);
    }   
    res.end();
  }); 
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I want to avoid...just want it to be automatic based on path or filename.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you post an small example?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. Am I still misunderstanding what you're looking for?

Comment: I didn't explain it as well as I could, but I meant static content served using express.static(). I can't see where/how to configure such content - it just gets served automatically.

Even for those where an explicit route is in place (like in your edit), I thought there might be some kind of middleware which might automatically inject the content type, instead of having to explicitly include it in every route.

Comment: The example with a complete path did not work for me. `res.contentType("path/to/image.png")` came out with an incorrect content-type, but `res.contentType("image.png")` worked great.

Comment: res.contentType(path.basename("path/to/image.png"));

Answer (score 5):

Express uses Connect, Connect uses Mime, and Mime includes the files ***mime.types*** (with default mime types from Apache) and ***node.types*** (with some further types contributed by node community). You could just customize one of these files within your copy of mime in node_modules to add your required content type, or Mime also has an API that lets you specify additional content-types or .types files to load from your code.

https://github.com/broofa/node-mime

Comment: Adding mime definitions through `require("mime").define(...)` does not work. Might it be because express bundles it's own mime module? How do I access the bundled mime module?

Answer (score 0):

Download this [database](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/1.3.x/conf/mime.types) (or  [Another link](http://cv.abdennoor.com/cdn/mime.types) ) : mime.types: , then

```
 var db_mimes=[],mime_ext=''
$.get('mime.types',{},function(d){
   var lines=d.split('\n').filter(function(e){ /* filter which starts with #*/})

    lines.forEach(function(line){
       mime_ext=line.split(' ')
        mime_ext[1].split(' ').forEach(function(ext){
             db_mimes.push({e:ext,m:mime_ext[0]})
         });
       //create object for each line . i.e: {mime:'',extension}
    });


});
```

Then if you have fo example `var fname="myfile.png"`

```
var extension=fname.substr((~-this.lastIndexOf(".") >>> 0) + 2) // get extension from name
var minme=db_mimes.filter(function(el){return el.e === extension})[0]
```

---

Comment: I change the link , click again & remove vote-down : https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/1.3.x/conf/mime.types

Comment: Not at all . you can check  also my other answer wich is based on Node.JS :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37891276/747579

Answer (score 0):

Run the following cmd :

```
npm install xmimetype ;
```

Then , in your code :

```
  var xm=require("xmimetype");

  xm.mimetypeOf("java"); 
  xm.mimetypeOf("./lib/Person.java"); 
  // -> text/x-java-source

  xm.mimetypeOf("docx"); 
  xm.mimetypeOf("./lib/overview.docx"); 
  // -> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

For more info , check [GIT repository](https://github.com/abdennour/xmimetype) .

---

The opposite is available :

```
  xm.extensionsOf("image/jpeg");
 // -> [ 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'jpe' ]
```