# Express: Incorrect MIME type for background images

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, mime-types

I’m having an issue with rendering background images referenced in my CSS.

The following is logged in the web inspector

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html.
```

The background image works fine locally - **it’s only when it’s deployed to heroku that it’s not working**.

I have my front-end assets in a `/public` dir.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public’)));
```

I am using [component](https://github.com/component/component) to build up my frontend, so I’m referencing my built assets (CSS/JS) from `public/build/` which is all working fine.

I’ve looked at [express-setting-content-type-based-on-path-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109732/express-setting-content-type-based-on-path-file) and [How do I set a MIME type before sending a file in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971918/how-do-i-set-a-mime-type-before-sending-a-file-in-node-js), but have had no luck.

I’ve also looked at the [res.set() api](http://expressjs.com/api#res.set) and tried to add this to my router.

```
// referencing my image build/background/images/my-image.png

app.get('/build/background/images/:file', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', ‘image/png’);
  res.send(req.params.file);
});
```

The above has in fact changed the content type from ‘text/html’ to ‘image/png’, however the image does not display locally or on heroku. 
The thumbnail is also broken in web inspector, yet the path to the image is correct.

In ‘Finder’ if I inspect the image - it’s says it’s kind is 'Alias'.

Comment: What is the type and/or contents of `req.params.file` (e.g. what does `console.dir(req.params.file)` show)?

Comment: @mscdex nothing actually.

    `app.get('/build/background/images/:file',function(req,res){
      console.dir('req.params.file is ', req.params.file);
    });`
   
This outputs `'req.params.file is '`

Comment: And running in debug mode:

`express:router dispatching GET /build/background/images/my-image.png (/build/background/images/my-image.png) +3ms`

`express:router matched get /build/background/images/:file +0ms`

`'req.params.file is '`

Comment: You can't use `console.dir()` like that. It has to be just `console.dir(req.params.file);` *or* you can do `console.log('req.params.file is', require('util').inspect(req.params.file));`

Comment: @mscdex ok thanks. This outputs the filename
`req.params.file is 'my-image.png'`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `res.send();`, it's sending the literal value of whatever you pass to it. So in this case, you're sending the string `'my-image.png'` to the client with `Content-Type: image/png`. To send the actual contents of `my-image.png` instead, you might look at using the [`res.sendfile()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendfile) method.

Comment: I've looked at res.sendFile() and altered my route to.

`app.get('/build/background/images/:file',function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/build/background/images/'+ req.params.file);
});`

Once again, works locally, not on heroku.

Comment: I also tried

`var mime = require('mime');
app.get('/build/background/images/:file',function(req, res){
  var file = req.params.file;
  var type = mime.lookup(file);
  res.set('Content-Type', type);
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/build/background/images/'+ req.params.file);
});`

This give sets the correct type for the image on heroku, but the image doesn't display in the browser - and in web inspector it shows the 'broken image' icon

Answer (score 0):

Although I've had some great feedback from @mscdex - the issue is a result of the symlinks to background images that are created by [component](https://github.com/component/component) on heroku.