# html view can not load css style because of MIME-type error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created super simple express app which will display one home.html view from view directory. Everything is ok `home.html` is displayed but there is no any css styles that i added. In the console i get only one error:

[image]

I tried to solve my problem with another answers from stack that I found like:

- change app.use()

  - from -> `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))`
  - to -> `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')))`

Okay here you can see how my directory structure looks like

[image]

As you can see I created public folder and inside of this folder i keep my css styles, so under the url: `http://localhost:8080/public/css/style.css` I should see my css styles but I can see only error

[image]

But in the same time under this url `http://localhost:8080/css/style.css` I can find my css file

[image]

I am really confused and I do not know what I am doing wrong. I will be very glad If any of you help me.

- app.js

  ```js
  const express = require('express');
  const path = require('path');
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
  const flash = require('connect-flash');
  const routes = require('./routes/index');
  const app = express();

  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(flash());
  app.use('/', routes);

  module.exports = app;
  ```
- server.js

  ```js
  const app = require('./app');

  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

  const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
      console.log(`Server is up on ${server.address().port}`);
  });
  ```
- home.html

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css">
      <title>Express</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Express</h1>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- style.css

  ```css
  body {
      background: #f6f6f6;
  }
  h1 {
      color: green;
  }
  ```

Comment: because you are sending css with mimetype `text/html` it should be `text/css`

Comment: where in ```<link>``` in home.html ? i add: ```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css">``` so type is ```text/css```. Or you mean another place?

Comment: from sever side it should be `text/css` mimetype. in your html it's not necessary to add `type` attribute.

Comment: How can i set MIME-type on my server ? Should i create another endpoint for this css request ?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109732/express-setting-content-type-based-on-path-file

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">. It must work. express.static makes your public folder equals to http://localhost:3000/. This will map to the public folder directly. You do not need to give public again.

Comment: Yes @AmaranadhMeda yes you are right thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I made mistake with express server configuration. Instead of serving static file like

- `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`
- `app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

This happened because /public directory was served under root url