# MIME Type Mismatch in Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, mime-types

I'm trying to load a page that uses JS (in a different location) from Express. However when I load the page, I always get a MIME type mismatch, like the following:

`The resource from “http://localhost:3000/home/lucid-user/lucid/lucidApp-ubuntu/node_modules/datamaps/dist/datamaps.world.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`

I've seen that the error comes as the script element rejects those responses with incorrect MIME types if the X-content option of `nosniff` is passed. How can I either:

1. Fix the content response to send the correct header (javascript)
2. Remove the nosniff option

**lucidmap.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="/home/lucid-user/lucid/lucidApp-ubuntu/node_modules/d3/build/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/home/lucid-user/lucid/lucidApp-ubuntu/node_modules/topojson/dist/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="/home/lucid-user/lucid/lucidApp-ubuntu/node_modules/datamaps/dist/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>

<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<script>
    var map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('container')});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Express.js** code snippet

```
app.get('/lucidmap', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/home/lucid-user/lucid/lucidApp-ubuntu/views/app/lucidmap.html');
});
```

Browser used is Mozilla 77.0.1 64-bit for Ubuntu.

Comment: How do you serve the `.js` files?

Comment: @eol I just call the script file from the HTML, you can't do that?

Comment: Well, when loading `lucidmap.html`, your browser will request the three `.js` files (from your `<script>`-tags). You need to serve those files as well from your server.

Comment: @eol oh, so I'll need to serve the files using Express as well, similar to this: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: If you need help setting up the static-serving I can post an answer - let me know.

Comment: Check this thread: [express setting content type based on path file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109732/express-setting-content-type-based-on-path-file)

Comment: Check this thread for answers: [express-setting-content-type-based-on-path-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109732/express-setting-content-type-based-on-path-file)

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful to see the Express code, where you include the static/public directory.

Here is how it should be done:
In your express code write something like:

```
app.use("/public", express.static("/home/lucid-user/lucid/lucidApp-ubuntu/node_modules/datamaps/dist"));
```

Add all the links you want to have in the "/public" directory as follows in your express code:

```
...
app.use("/public", express.static("/home/lucid-user/lucid/lucidApp-ubuntu/node_modules/datamaps/dist"));
app.use("/public", express.static("/home/lucid-user/lucid/lucidApp-ubuntu/node_modules/topojson/dist/"));
...
```

Then you only need to write in your HTML Code:

```
<script src="/public/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/topojson.min.js"></script>
```

Then another tip: Best practice is to place all your  tags inside the  tag, at the very end, just before .
It should look like this:

```
<body>
    .
    .
    <script src="/public/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/topojson.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Placing the script tag at the end of the body is far from a best practice. It's a terrible practice, if you need the script to load after the body, you should use the defer or async attributes.